# What is the correct pattern matching string to exclude records containing "x"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pattern-matching, sql-server-2019

```
DECLARE @data TABLE
(   sample_text VARCHAR(20))

DECLARE @match TABLE
(   match_text VARCHAR(20),
    return_value INT
)

INSERT INTO @data
VALUES ('sample'),
       ('text'),
       ('fuzzy'),
       ('kittens')

INSERT INTO @match
VALUES ('%e%', 1),
       ('[^t]%', 2),
       ('%[^t]%', 3)

SELECT *
  FROM @data  d 
  JOIN @match m ON d.sample_text LIKE m.match_text
```

I'm trying to return a value based on whether the data in a field matches a regular expression.

The regular expression should enable me to match positive (e.g. starts with T) and negative (e.g. does NOT start with T) without having to change the underlying SQL.

Simple cases work (e.g. contains "e", doesn't start with "t"), but when I want to return rows which don't contain "t" I have a problem.

I know I could use `NOT LIKE` in any number of ways but I am looking for a generic solution.

The only rows which have a return value of 3 should be "sample" and "fuzzy". "text" and "kittens" should not match because they each contain the character "t".

In my head `"%[^t]%"` means "not containing character 't'". In your answer could you clarify what it really translates to? Can you translate your suggestion in the same way to help me understand?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: `LIKE` is not regex, don't kid yourself that it is. `%` matches any character if any, `[^` matches any single character NOT in the brackets, `t]` specifies the character `t` to not match, `%` matches any remaining characters if any. So it will match anything that contains a character that is not `t` somewhere even if it does contain a `t`

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface, so how would I fix the "match" string so that the record wont be returned if it contains a ```t``` regardless of any other characters?

Comment: `'%[^t]%'` means "containing at least one character that is _not_ `'t'`". You could do something (horrible) with an additional column, e.g. `NotLike as Bit`, and then build your logic out as `case when d.Sample_Text like m.Match_Text then 1 - m.NotLike else m.NotLike end = 1`. Or `( m.NotLike = 0 and d.Sample_Text like m.Match_Text ) or ( m.NotLike = 1 and d.Sample_Text not like m.Match_Text )`. Instead of another column you could corrupt the pattern and pull it apart, e.g. if the first character is [`'¬'`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation#Notation) then remove it and invert the logic.

Comment: You can't. There is no equivalent to `+` from regex, so you can't do `[^t]+`, you have to use `NOT LIKE`. Was about to suggest a second column with `case`

Comment: Cant be done simply with pattern matching seems to be the consensus. I will have to change my approach. Thanks All. (makes me feel a bit better about not being able to get it to work actually) Thanks for helping me clarify WHY it wasn't working too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it is useful to anyone...

As always, the actual problem is slightly more complicated than the minimal steps to reproduce it we post here.

My specific scenario involves matching on 4 separate columns so adding a new column for each of the existing ones to represent the `NOT LIKE` scenario makes an already cumbersome solution that much more so.

Given the determination that pattern matching wasn't going to get me there, the solution I settled on was to have separate rows for the `LIKE` scenario and the `NOT LIKE` scenario and then grouping them together to get the result.

```
DECLARE @data TABLE
(   sample_text VARCHAR(20))

DECLARE @match TABLE
(   rule_type    INT, -- 1 = Include, 0 = Exclude
    match_text   VARCHAR(20),
    return_value INT
)

INSERT INTO @data
VALUES ('sample' ),
       ('ample'  ),
       ('dimple' ),
       ('text'   ),
       ('fuzzy'  ),
       ('kittens')

INSERT INTO @match
VALUES ('1', '%mple%', 1),
       ('0', 'd%'    , 1),
       ('1', '[^t]%' , 2),
       ('0', '%mple%', 2)

SELECT sample_text, return_value
  FROM @data  d 
  JOIN @match m ON d.sample_text LIKE m.match_text
 GROUP BY sample_text, return_value
HAVING MIN(rule_type) <> 0 -- any number of "include" rules can match but if any "exclude" rule is matched the record is not returned.
```

Answer (score 0):

You exclude records by inverting the sense of the `LIKE` match, i.e.: `NOT LIKE`.

As a general rule any query with `NOT IN` or `NOT LIKE` in it is going to perform horribly at scale, but here is one way you could look for items not matching a given pattern...

```sql
DECLARE @data TABLE
(   sample_text VARCHAR(20))

DECLARE @match TABLE
(   match VARCHAR(20),
    not_match VARCHAR(20),
    return_value INT
)

INSERT INTO @data
VALUES ('sample'),
       ('text'),
       ('fuzzy'),
       ('kittens')

INSERT INTO @match
VALUES ('%e%', null, 1),
       (null, 't%', 2),
       (null, '%t%', 3)

SELECT *
FROM @data  d 
JOIN @match m
  ON (m.match is not null and d.sample_text LIKE m.match)
  OR (m.not_match is not null and d.sample_text NOT LIKE m.not_match);
```